# Flutter: Row layout issue

Tags: flutter

I need to layout two elements in the row. They should have minimum width.

The first element is always short and always fits the container width.

If the second element overflows container's width it should be clipped.

Here's what I need to achieve.

[image: layout example]

Here's a code
https://dartpad.dev/?id=a9b698d5eb89cfddaca000af17e0c28d

Asking for help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) as it expands, but does not require the child to fill the available space.

```
Row(
  children: const [
    Flexible(
      child: CloudWidget(
        child: Text(
          'Not expanded',
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Flexible(
      child: CloudWidget(
        child: Text(
          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. I bet I tried that but for some reason it didn't work. I have more complex widgets inside my CloudWidget so maybe there was some issue.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to wrap your widget with Expanded widget and write which type of overflow you need
You can look into below code

```
Expanded(
            child: CloudWidget(child: 
              Text('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                   softWrap: false, 
                   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                   )
             )
 ),
```

Comment: I used Expanded in the example. You just used the second row from my example in your answer. It works if the widget is long and need to be clipped, but it expands short widgets, which I don't want to.